# Receiving a KeyError for 'request' in DRF serializer when using detail_route in my ViewSet

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

This is my ViewSet:

```
class PostViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = PostSerializer
    permission_classes = (IsAuthenticated, IsOwnerDeleteOrReadOnly)

    def get_queryset(self):
        return Post.objects.filter(location=self.request.user.userextended.location)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        serializer.save(owner=self.request.user, location=self.request.user.userextended.location)

    def get_serializer_context(self):
            """
            Extra context provided to the serializer class.
            """
            return {
                'format': self.format_kwarg,
                'view': self,
                'location': self.request.user.userextended.location
            }

    @detail_route(methods=['post'], permission_classes=[IsAuthenticated, IsFromLocation])
    def like(self, request, pk=None):
        post = self.get_object()
        post.usersVoted.add(request.user)
        return Response(status=status.HTTP_204_NO_CONTENT)

    @detail_route(methods=['get'], permission_classes=[IsAuthenticated, ValidPostPkInKwargs, IsFromPostLocation])
    def replies(self, request, pk=None):
        post = self.get_object()
        replies = post.postreply_set.all()
        serializer = PostReplySerializer(replies, many=True)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

And this is my PostReplySerializer:

```
class PostReplySerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = serializers.SlugRelatedField(slug_field='username', read_only=True)
    voted = serializers.SerializerMethodField()

    def get_voted(self, obj):
        return self.context['request'].user in obj.usersVoted.all()

    class Meta:
        model = PostReply
        fields = ('id', 'owner', 'post', 'voted', 'location')
```

The error points to the line

```
return self.context['request'].user in obj.usersVoted.all()
```

and says:

```
KeyError at /URL/20/replies/
'request'
```

Any idea why DRF says 'request' is a key error even though (from my understanding) it should be automatically in `self.context`?

Note that `PostViewSet` works perfectly fine for all other requests (if I get a Post, get a list of posts etc.). It just doesn't work for `replies`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not in self.context because you have overridden `get_serializer_context`. `request` object is attached to context via this method. Just add `request: self.request` in your return statement of `get_serializer_context` that would solve the problem. Take a look at default implementation of `get_serializer_context` here https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/generics.py to understand more. Hope it helps..

**EDIT**
Since you are using different serializer(`PostReplySerializer`) in detail_route, you need to create serializer instance like `serializer = PostReplySerializer(replies, many=True, context={'request': self.request})`

Comment: Strange. Even when I add `'request': self.request,` in the return statement, I still get the same error. could it possibly have something to do with the fact that the serializer I am using in my detail_route is different than the one I am using in my viewset? Edit: Even when I remove `get_serializer_context()` completely from my viewset and not override it, I still get the same error as well for some reason.

Comment: yea.. Thats because you are using different serializer in detail_route. Try passing `context={'request': self.request}` while creating the serializer instance. like `serializer = PostReplySerializer(replies, many=True, context={'request': self.request})`. This would solve the problem.

Comment: Oh okay thanks! Any idea why the detail_route does not receive the serializer contexts even though it is part of the same viewset? Is there any documentation which mentions it? I'm asking just so I can understand what exactly is going on. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Good question. Actually take a look at the actual code of view set that get the correct serializer https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/generics.py#L104  here whatever seraizer you are giving in `serializer_class` will only get the `context` automatically. Other serializers you have to manually give the context while creating the serializer instance. Hope this is helpful..